# Whitespace created when using if statements

Tags: templating, whitespace

I am using the following block of code in a template:

```html
<hr class="rule">

{% if entry.features | length %}
    <div class="feature-block">
        <h4 class="is-uppercase">Features</h4>
        <ul class="features fa-ul">
        {% for block in entry.features %}
            <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i> {{ block.feature }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The if statement is adding whitespace to the markup which causes styling issues.

[image: Whitespace]

How can I correct this? Do I need to format the code block differently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the twig documentation regarding whitespace control:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#whitespace-control

In short, wrap the area where you want to remove whitespace in `{% spaceless %} ... {% endspaceless %}`, and use the `-` character inside tags to trim whitespace before and/or after.

Answer (score 12):

You can also the hyphen/dash '-' modifier for shorter syntax and in place of the spaceless tags. Plus you get a bit more granular control where you want it, like trimming only leading or trailing space.

#### Example 1 taken from Twig Docs: [Whitespace Control](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#whitespace-control), this would remove whitespace around the if's and output of value.

```
{% set value = 'no spaces' %}
{#- No leading/trailing whitespace -#}
{%- if true -%}
    {{- value -}}
{%- endif -%}

{# output 'no spaces' #}
```

#### Example 2 is a possible real world scenario for retentive space people:

```
{%- set metaDescription = 'Page description.' -%}
{%- set metaKeywords = 'word1 word2 word3' -%}
{%- set pageTitle = 'A Title' %}

{% if metaKeywords is defined -%}
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{ metaKeywords }}" />
{%- endif %}

{% if metaDescription is defined -%}
    <meta name="description" content="{{ metaDescription }}" />
{%- endif %}

{% if pageTitle is defined -%}
    <title>{{ pageTitle }}</title>
{%- endif %}
```

Rendered output:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="word1 word2 word3" />
<meta name="description" content="Page description." />
<title>A Title</title>
```

Comment: But why? I mean this is super ugly, super annoying to type, so why isn't this a global default???

Answer (score 4):

You have several different options, depending on what you want to do:

- The spaceless function, which removes whitespace between HTML tags:

  ```
  {% spaceless %}
      <div>
          <strong>foo</strong>
      </div>
  {% endspaceless %}

  {# output will be <div><strong>foo</strong></div> #}
  ```
- The trim filter, which removes whitespace from the beginning/end of a string:

  ```
  {{ block.feature | trim }}
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You could always just use the [Minify plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/minify) and wrap whatever you want in:

```
{% minify %}

{% endminify %}
```

If works with inline CSS/JS, too.